# Cannot find module: 'utils/ClassNames.js'. Make sure this package is installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I mimic code at https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/blob/master/src/components/utils/ClassNames.js

and

https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/blob/master/src/showcase/datatable/DataTablePaginatorDemo.js

My code

[image]

```js
export function classNames(...args) {
  if (args) {
    let classes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      let className = args[i];
      if (!className) continue;
      const type = typeof className;
      if (type === 'string' || type === 'number') {
        classes.push(className);
      } else if (type === 'object') {
        const _classes = Array.isArray(className)
          ? className
          : Object.entries(className).map(([key, value]) =>
              !!value ? key : null
            );

        classes = _classes.length
          ? classes.concat(_classes.filter((c) => !!c))
          : classes;
      }
    }
    return classes.join(' ');
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Component } from 'react';
import { DataTable } from 'primereact/datatable';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
import { Toast } from 'primereact/toast';
import { InputText } from 'primereact/inputtext';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { AcctgTransService } from '../service/AcctgTransService';
import { getTokenCookie } from '../TokenCookie';
import { Dialog } from 'primereact/dialog';
import { Dropdown } from 'primereact/dropdown';
import { Calendar } from 'primereact/calendar';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Const, ServiceHandle } from '../utilities';
import i18n from 'i18next';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Ripple } from 'primereact/core';
import { CustomerService } from '../service/CustomerService';
import { classNames } from 'utils/ClassNames.js';

export class AcctgTrans2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      customers1: [],
      customers2: [],
      customers3: [],
      first1: 0,
      rows1: 10,
      first2: 0,
      rows2: 10,
      currentPage: 1,
      pageInputTooltip: "Press 'Enter' key to go to this page.",
    };

    this.customerService = new CustomerService();

    this.onCustomPage1 = this.onCustomPage1.bind(this);
    this.onCustomPage2 = this.onCustomPage2.bind(this);
    this.onPageInputKeyDown = this.onPageInputKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.onPageInputChange = this.onPageInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  onCustomPage1(event) {
    this.setState({
      first1: event.first,
      rows1: event.rows,
      currentPage: event.page + 1,
    });
  }

  onCustomPage2(event) {
    this.setState({
      first2: event.first,
      rows2: event.rows,
    });
  }

  onPageInputKeyDown(event, options) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      const page = parseInt(this.state.currentPage);
      if (page < 0 || page > options.totalPages) {
        this.setState({
          pageInputTooltip: `Value must be between 1 and ${options.totalPages}.`,
        });
      } else {
        const first = this.state.currentPage ? options.rows * (page - 1) : 0;

        this.setState({
          first1: first,
          pageInputTooltip: "Press 'Enter' key to go to this page.",
        });
      }
    }
  }

  onPageInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({ currentPage: event.target.value });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.customerService
      .getCustomersLarge()
      .then((data) => this.setState({ customers1: data }));
    this.customerService
      .getCustomersLarge()
      .then((data) => this.setState({ customers2: data }));
    this.customerService
      .getCustomersLarge()
      .then((data) => this.setState({ customers3: data }));
  }

  render() {
    const paginatorLeft = (
      <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-refresh" className="p-button-text" />
    );
    const paginatorRight = (
      <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-cloud" className="p-button-text" />
    );
    const template1 = {
      layout:
        'PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink RowsPerPageDropdown CurrentPageReport',
      PrevPageLink: (options) => {
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            className={options.className}
            onClick={options.onClick}
            disabled={options.disabled}>
            <span className="p-p-3">Previous</span>
            <Ripple />
          </button>
        );
      },
      NextPageLink: (options) => {
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            className={options.className}
            onClick={options.onClick}
            disabled={options.disabled}>
            <span className="p-p-3">Next</span>
            <Ripple />
          </button>
        );
      },
      PageLinks: (options) => {
        if (
          (options.view.startPage === options.page &&
            options.view.startPage !== 0) ||
          (options.view.endPage === options.page &&
            options.page + 1 !== options.totalPages)
        ) {
          const className = classNames(options.className, {
            'p-disabled': true,
          });
          return (
            <span className={className} style={{ userSelect: 'none' }}>
              ...
            </span>
          );
        }
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            className={options.className}
            onClick={options.onClick}>
            {options.page + 1}
            <Ripple />
          </button>
        );
      },
      RowsPerPageDropdown: (options) => {
        const dropdownOptions = [
          { label: 10, value: 10 },
          { label: 20, value: 20 },
          { label: 50, value: 50 },
          { label: 'All', value: options.totalRecords },
        ];

        return (
          <Dropdown
            value={options.value}
            options={dropdownOptions}
            onChange={options.onChange}
            appendTo={document.body}
          />
        );
      },
      CurrentPageReport: (options) => {
        return (
          <span
            className="p-mx-3"
            style={{ color: 'var(--text-color)', userSelect: 'none' }}>
            Go to{' '}
            <InputText
              size="2"
              className="p-ml-1"
              value={this.state.currentPage}
              tooltip={this.state.pageInputTooltip}
              onKeyDown={(e) => this.onPageInputKeyDown(e, options)}
              onChange={this.onPageInputChange}
            />
          </span>
        );
      },
    };
    const template2 = {
      layout: 'RowsPerPageDropdown CurrentPageReport PrevPageLink NextPageLink',
      RowsPerPageDropdown: (options) => {
        const dropdownOptions = [
          { label: 10, value: 10 },
          { label: 20, value: 20 },
          { label: 50, value: 50 },
        ];

        return (
          <>
            <span
              className="p-mx-1"
              style={{ color: 'var(--text-color)', userSelect: 'none' }}>
              Items per page:{' '}
            </span>
            <Dropdown
              value={options.value}
              options={dropdownOptions}
              onChange={options.onChange}
              appendTo={document.body}
            />
          </>
        );
      },
      CurrentPageReport: (options) => {
        return (
          <span
            style={{
              color: 'var(--text-color)',
              userSelect: 'none',
              width: '120px',
              textAlign: 'center',
            }}>
            {options.first} - {options.last} of {options.totalRecords}
          </span>
        );
      },
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="content-section implementation">
          <div className="card">
            <h5>Basic</h5>
            <DataTable
              value={this.state.customers1}
              paginator
              paginatorTemplate="CurrentPageReport FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink RowsPerPageDropdown"
              currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords}"
              rows={10}
              rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 50]}
              paginatorLeft={paginatorLeft}
              paginatorRight={paginatorRight}>
              <Column field="name" header="Name"></Column>
              <Column field="country.name" header="Country"></Column>
              <Column field="company" header="Company"></Column>
              <Column
                field="representative.name"
                header="Representative"></Column>
            </DataTable>

            <h5>Custom Paginator Template</h5>
            <DataTable
              value={this.state.customers2}
              paginator
              paginatorTemplate={template1}
              first={this.state.first1}
              rows={this.state.rows1}
              onPage={this.onCustomPage1}>
              <Column field="name" header="Name"></Column>
              <Column field="country.name" header="Country"></Column>
              <Column field="company" header="Company"></Column>
              <Column
                field="representative.name"
                header="Representative"></Column>
            </DataTable>

            <DataTable
              value={this.state.customers3}
              paginator
              paginatorTemplate={template2}
              first={this.state.first2}
              rows={this.state.rows2}
              onPage={this.onCustomPage2}
              paginatorClassName="p-jc-end"
              className="p-mt-6">
              <Column field="name" header="Name"></Column>
              <Column field="country.name" header="Country"></Column>
              <Column field="company" header="Company"></Column>
              <Column
                field="representative.name"
                header="Representative"></Column>
            </DataTable>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Error

[image]

```
E:\monte\gsreact>npm run build

> gsreact@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build && rmdir /s E:\xx\xx\runtime\base-component\webroot\screen\webroot\xx && move build E:\xx\xx\runtime\base-component\webroot\screen\webroot\xx

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

.\src\components\AcctgTrans2.js
Cannot find module: 'utils/ClassNames.js'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install utils/ClassNames.js.



E:\xx\xx>
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: I just updated my answer, and include the configuration, if you want to configure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Solution**

You can change:

`import { classNames } from 'utils/ClassNames.js';`

To:

`import { classNames } from './utils/ClassNames.js';`

Without the relative route, the import thinks it's a library.

**Configuration**

If you want to configure and you've used `create-react-app`: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports

In any other case:

- https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver
- https://github.com/entwicklerstube/babel-plugin-root-import